# Stop VLC player from saving effects & filter settings

Tags: vlc-media-player

VLC Player v1.1.11
Windows 7 Ultimate

VLC player launches each new video with setting I used once to brighten a dark video.  On a second computer, VLC player opens all videos rotated 270 which was a feature I used once.  I now have to manually uncheck Image adjust on one computer & uncheck Transform on another for each video to have it play without these custom settings.

I've custom mapped VLC Hotkeys that I use extensively.  As a result, I do not want to "reset preferences" and lose my Hotkey mapping.

VLC > Tools > Settings > Video Effects > Basic > Image Adjust (Brightness, Contrast, etc.)
VLC > Tools > Settings > Video Effects > Basic > Transform (Rotate 90, 180, 270)

Is there a setting I'm not finding to stop VLC from applying a one time adjustment to all videos?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

In the "Adjustments and Effects" dialog, the first tab (Audio Effects) should have the checkbox "**Write changes to config**" which is intended to save any Settings to the config-file.

Toggle the "Write changes to config" setting before turning off all the filters.  Quit VLC and it should should save the changes to the Config file.

*This didn't work for me.*  If this doesn't work for you, you may need to manually remove the filter settings from your config-file (a textfile with all the VLC settings/preferences).  This same file is also where the Hotkey preferences are stored.

The easiest way is to save your Hotkey preferences to a new Textfile, then delete the config-file entirely;  then relaunch VLC --- it will create a new config-file; then quit VLC and import your Hotkey settings once more.

- [Where does VLC store its config file?](http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html#Config)
- [How to import/export Hotkey settings](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=103840)

A harder way would be to read the Config file carefully and remove the offending Filter/effect preference.